# How to handle new line character while creating csv file in android

Tags: java, android, csv

I am creating CSV file in android. File is being created successfully but if there is new line character in content then the content formatting is disturbed.
 please suggest how to handle new line character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If additional details can be made available on how the data is received and processed, a more detailed example of how to fit the replacements into your methods can be provided.

---

You should replace new-line characters as they arrive with something easier to handle in the CSV file. I suggest the 2-character string "\n", but you can also replace it with a blank, dash, or remove the character altogether.

While you are at it, you probably also want to handle line-feed "\r" and tab "\t". Be sure to escape the backslash characters.

Example (pseudo-code):

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
char c;
loop-through-characters {
    if(c == '\n') {
        // Replace new-line with "\n".
        s.append("\\n");
    } else if(c == '\r') {
        // Replace line-feed with "\r".
        s.append("\\r");
    } else if(c == '\t') {
        // Replace tab with space " ".
        s.append(" ");
    } else {
        // Otherwise, append the character as-is.
        s.append(c);
    }
}

// Process the bytes[] in StringBuffer s as you would have 
// previously processed the raw bytes[].
```